# Excel formula to sum an array based on multiple criteria of arrays -- Fantasy Football

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

I have 2 tables and need to use criteria from table1 (Team) to look up information from Schedule2 (Team's Schedule for the year) and then use that array from Schedule2 to find the matches in table1 (opponents) and pair that with the criteria of matching the position within table 1 (position = position) to then sum up the associated numbers that match (2021 opp position points) to calculate the expected total points for the year.

In English: use the team to look up the schedule, use the schedule to look up the array of opponents the team has for the year, use the array of opponents for the year to find the opponents in table1, and then match the position of the current row to the position that is playing each of those opponents, and then sum up the associated points.

Goal: This is to calculate a forecast of each team's position's total points for the year based on how many points their opponents for the year are currently giving away to each position.

Explained Example: So if Dallas WR plays NYG, MIA, WAS, and MIA again, sum up the total points NYG, MIA, WAS, and MIA are currently giving to WRs they are currently play against.

FYI WR = Wide Receiver RB = Running Back, TE = Tight End D/ST = Defense string, QB = Quarterback

I can't use helper cells and need a single formula. Schedule2 will give duplicate values (Some teams play the same team twice and each of those values need to be calculated and not considered unique and not counted just once.

The current formula I have is below but it only seemed to work for one row and didnt work when I drug it down to the row below. could be a referencing issue but I didnt notice anything that would cause this.

The first part of the formula is meant to get the total for the non-duplicated values and the second is meant to get the duplicated values.

```
= SUM( IF( ISERROR( MATCH( Table1[[#All],[Position]],G14,0) 
                                   * MATCH(Table1[[#All],[Opponent]],INDEX(Schedule2,0,MATCH(Table1[@Team],Schedules!$AU$3:$CA$3,0)),0) ),
           0,
           Table1[[#All],[2021 Opp Position]]))
+ SUM( IF( ISERROR( MATCH( Table1[[#All],[Opponent]],
                           IF( COUNTIF( INDEX( Schedule2, 0, MATCH(Table1[@Team],Schedules!$AU$3:$CA$3,0) ), INDEX(Schedule2,0,MATCH(Table1[@Team],Schedules!$AU$3:$CA$3,0)))=2,
                               INDEX(Schedule2,0,MATCH(Table1[@Team],Schedules!$AU$3:$CA$3,0)),
                               ""), 0 )
                    * MATCH(Table1[[#All],[Position]],G14,0)
                    * MATCH(Table1[[#All],[Opponent]],INDEX( Schedule2,
                                                             0,
                                                             MATCH(Table1[@Team],Schedules!$AU$3:$CA$3,0) ),0) ),
           0,
           Table1[[#All],[2021 Opp Position]] ) )
```

[image: Table1]

[image: Schedule2]

Comment: You should edit this and add screenshots and a detailed explanation of what the problem is and what you have tried. Not many ppl will download a file (particularly xlsm).

Comment: Thanks Mark hopefully these updates will better describe the question